# C# Inheritance wrapper code

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class Base {
   public void execute() {
      //'preexecute code'
      child.execute();
      //'postexecute code'
   }
}

public class Child : Base {
{
   public void execute() {
      //'Some child specific code'
   }
}
```

Is there any way in C# to support an execution model like above where you call a function in the child class from the base class. The "preexecute code" and "postexecute code" is common and should be ran every time "execute" is called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend you an abstract method that is invoked from the base (known as the [Template Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx)):

```
abstract class Base {
  void Foo() {
    DoSomething();
    Bar();
    DoSomethingElse();
  }

  protected abstract void Bar();
}

class Child : Base {
  protected override void Bar() {
    DoSomethingChildSpecific();
  }
}
```

You can implement a very specific part in `Bar` (*primitive operation* in the [Template Method Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx)) for each child, and the `Base` invokes it in the right context. Consumers can therefore not mess up the execution sequence `Foo`, unlike if they were able to override `Foo` itself.

Comment: This is the best solution because the `protected abstract` prevents the API user to invoke only the specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

i think u r looking for

```
public abstract class Base {
   public abstract void execute();
}

public class Child : Base {
{
   public override void execute() {
      //'Some child specific code'
   }
}
```